# yum case (in)sensitive

Tags: yum, case-sensitivity

As far as I know, `yum list` is case insensitive, while `yum install` and `yum remove` are case sensitive -- probably as a security feature to prevent unintended system changes.

Is there a way to change the case sensitivity of any `yum` command?

Comment: No,there is not

Comment: Can you help me understand the use case here? When would you want this?

Comment: When installing or removing a package whose name might contain uppercase chars but I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but there is a workaround. When doing yum install and yum remove, to make it work case insensitive.

```
  pack=Zvbi; yum install $(yum list $pack | cut -d' ' -f1 | tail -n1)

  pack=iMaGeMaGiCk; yum install $(yum list $pack | cut -d' ' -f1 | tail -n1)
```

Comment: This won't always be valid - there are some package names that have capitals in them, and this workaround will break with those packages. An example is ImageMagick - `yum install imagemagick` won't do anything, but `yum install ImageMagick` works as expected.

Comment: @John is right, +1 however as this tip might come handy. I've edited the answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Another option might be to replace all uppercase letters with the `?` wildcard character: `echo ImageMagick AnotherPackage |tr [:upper:] '?'|xargs yum -y install`

Comment: Now i edited it to a better version that can run for ImageMagick.

Answer (score 4):

Currently yum does not support case insensitive operations on packages (install/remove), this way by design. There are some tickets/discussions on the Red Hat Bugzilla site about it.